WebSockets down stream is Rate-Limited Channels
We have a game which is running on our Django server. All calculations are made on the server.
We use WebSocket to communicate the game data to our front-end clients, which do the rendering.
But we have a problem. With the channels AsyncWebsocketConsumer, we have a while True loop that send a message 60 times per seconds to our client (we only have one for the moment).
After receiving some data, the client receives nothing (But we know that the server continue to send data).
I read a StackOverflow post that talk about a bufferedAmount, and volatile messages. but I'd like to know if we can avoid using a send queue when using django-channels to drop messages that can't be sent/received by the server/client, and let the others through.
Or if anyone has a better transmission solution for a game that needs to run server-side (like using UDP with another protocol available on the browser), but I don't know how.

I need to know a little bit about what kind of data we are communicating. Is it possible to only transact data with the user when they send data? In other words, is the data stream to the player a constant stream, or is this a turned based game where we can wait for a player command? If you are using the while True loop to check if the user is connected there's a better way to do that.

I prefer to specify that it's for a school project. It's a pong game, so the ball needs to be updated regularly.  Nevertheless, we used a Client-Side Prediction and Server Reconciliation technique (https://www.gabrielgambetta.com/client-side-prediction-server-reconciliation.html). That solved our problems.

very cool glad you got it working
